# Cant find the canvas layer node in godot game engine

Tags: godot

When i try to find the canvas layer option in my scene it doesn't seem to appear. But all other developers on YouTube seem to have no such problem

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. You may find the site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section and this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) checklist useful guidance for asking a good question.  It is easier for people to help you if you include the code that you've worked on to solve the problem and ideally provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

[`CanvasLayer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_canvaslayer.html) is a type of node. If you need it, you would have to add it to your scene.

If you use the "Add Child Node" option from the scene panel (Ctr+A by default) you will get the "Create new node" dialog. It presents a tree with the different type of nodes that Godot has registered.

In the tree of node types `CanvasLayer` should be directly under `Node` in the the tree, so not inside the `Spatial`, nor inside the `CanvasItem` branch, just down. If you have problems finding a type of node, you can use the search bar at the top of the dialog and type the name of the type of node you want.

---

Now, it is possible `CanvasLayer` is not registered. This can be because it has been disabled, or because you have an (unofficial? custom?) build that does not have it.

You can disable nodes from the option "Manage Editor Features" on the "Edit" menu. There you can create, select or remove editor profiles. And on each editor profile you can select what features are available, including the `CanvasLayer` node type (which should appear there assuming you have an official build). So make sure you don't have an editor profile, or you have an editor profile that has `CanvasLayer`.